# Install missing packages into Fedora LiveCD

Tags: linux, fedora, package-management, livecd

I have a Dell Inspiron 3180 netbook. I am trying to update the BIOS but it is only offered for Windows. The netbook runs Zorin 12.3 but [Wine is broken](https://bugs.launchpad.net/zorin-os/+bug/1775454). Since I can't use the netbook's OS to install the BIOS update I am trying to use a Fedora LiveCD.

I have a Fedora 28 LiveCD, and it is burned to a USB thumbdrive. The problem I am having is, the Live ISO lacks Wine. I tried a `yum update` and `yum install wine` but it failed due to lack of space for the root filesystem.

According to [Portable Wine](https://wiki.winehq.org/Portable_Wine), *"Once you have a persistent live-USB ready and working, installing Wine itself shouldn't be too hard at all..."*. But the discussion lacks the details to install Portable Wine.

[FedoraLiveCD](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FedoraLiveCD) seems to be a starting point but it lacks instructions for installing missing software into a LiveCD.

I feel like I am missing something obvious but I am not sure where I should be looking. Searching is turning out to be difficult because of the noise due to installing packages *from* a CD (and not *into* a LiveCD).

How do I install missing packages into the Fedora LiveCD (which is the thumbdrive)?

Comment: I pretty much highly doubt Wine will work for doing a BIOS update.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro - Yeah, I wondered that myself. One problem at a time.

Comment: Use FreeDOS  to flash the bios , it is more easy. It doesn't answer your question but it can be helpful to flash your BIOS.

Comment: @GAD3R It's good that some still realize that this is a site for Unix questions, but not necessarily for Unix answers.